# XFCE: Show all ssh terminals

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, xfce

My XFCE desktop has multiple workspaces, and I have terminals open across the workspaces, each terminal containing a ssh session.

I usually have around 10 SSH sessions open at a time, I was wondering if there was any way to set up a keyboard shortcut that would list all my open ssh sessions, and allow me to search for and select a session, which will switch to the appropriate terminal.

I'm open to other ideas, I just want to manage all my ssh sessions, so i can switch to the one I want quickly.

Note: I sometimes have duplicate sessions open to the same host, so having some way to mark each session for later search would be even nicer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My solution to that was to use multiple tabs on a single **xfce4-terminal** window with the nice `--drop-down` option bound to <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

That way you can see all the sessions on the tab names, which can even be renamed, and I can quickly switch between opened tabs with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>.

[More info on that.](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/dropdown)